# i want to convert 8 digit hexa decimel color code of #4CAF50 in android

Tags: android

**code snippet:**

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        colorDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

i want set the color in color drawable

Comment: "i want set the color in color drawable", so read ColorDrawable javadocs, whats unclear?

Comment: do you have a problem with the code?

Comment: ya. program is crashing

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.akku.titlebar/com.wisilica.TitleBar.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0000
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)

Comment: what is `R.color.mycolor` ?

Comment: thats my color name in color xml file

Comment: and how it is defined?

Comment: It may be R file error try to run your project after clean up.